# Dynamic quantization in Pytorch starts random training after quantization

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, yolov8

When I run following code for dynamic quantization it starts training with some random natural images for 100 epochs, I don't want to do training again. I have pretrained weights, I just want to quantize my pretrained weights to reduce inference time:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import torch
import torch.quantization

model=YOLO('pre_trained_weights.pt')

model.load_state_dict(torch.load('checkpoint.pth')) #donot know this step is necessary or not

qmodel = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(model, dtype = torch.quint8)
```

I tried above code and I am expecting that I just want to quantize my pretrained weights to reduce inference time

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic quantization is not available for Conv layer(Conv in YOLO). [Checkout the documentation here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html#quantization-api-summary). I believe it is going into calibration mode when you apply on layers which are not supported.

Comment: Yes, correct, dynamic quantization is not available for Conv Layer. I need to go for static quantization, can you suggest what changes I need to do in above mention code.

Comment: @HiteshTekchandani, I would suggest use dynamic quantization for linear layers and see how the model size and time required for evaluation/inference

Comment: If you want to do a static quantization, here is a great tutorial - https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/static_quantization_tutorial.html